# How to do flipping without using the inbuilt function flip in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

Can anyone help me with this problem, how to do flipping of an image without using the inbuilt flipping function  i.e. flip(src image, destination image , 1 or 0) in C++ using OpenCV. I am new to this software so please help.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the built-in functions?

Comment: Just was stuck up and wanted to do a lot of hard work :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a good reason not to use OpenCV [flip](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#flip) function, you can write your custom one.

For this example, I'll use `CV_8UC3` images. I'll point out at the end how to expand this to different formats.

Let's see first how to flip an image x axis, which corresponds to `cv::flip(src, dst, 1)`.  Given an `src` image, the `dst` image will have the same `y` coordinate, and `x` coordinate as `src.cols - 1 - x` coordinates. In practice:

```
void flip_lr(const Mat3b& src, Mat3b& dst)
{
    Mat3b _dst(src.rows, src.cols);
    for (int r = 0; r < _dst.rows; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < _dst.cols; ++c) {
            _dst(r, c) = src(r, src.cols - 1 - c);
        }
    }
    dst = _dst;
}
```

Then, to flip around y axis (corresponding to `cv::flip(src, dst, 0)`), `dst` will have the same `x` coordinate, and `y` as `src.rows - 1 - y`. However, you can reuse the above-mentioned function, simply transposing the `dst` matrix, apply flip on x axis, and then transpose back. In practice:

```
dst = src.t();
flip_lr(dst, dst);
dst = dst.t();
```

Then, to flip both axis, corresponding to `cv::flip(src, dst, -1)`, you need simply to combine the flip on x and y axis:

```
flip_lr(src, dst);
dst = dst.t();
flip_lr(dst, dst);
dst = dst.t();
```

You can wrap this functionality in a custom flip function that takes the same parameters as `cv::flip`:

```
void custom_flip(const Mat3b& src, Mat3b& dst, int code)
{
    if (code > 0)
    {   // Flip x axis
        flip_lr(src, dst);
    }
    else if (code == 0)
    {
        // Flip y axis
        dst = src.t();
        flip_lr(dst, dst);
        dst = dst.t();
    }
    else // code < 0
    {
        // Flip x and y axis
        flip_lr(src, dst);
        dst = dst.t();
        flip_lr(dst, dst);
        dst = dst.t();
    }
}
```

Note that you can adapt this to different format simply modifing the `flip_lr` function, and taking care to call the appropriate version inside `custom_flip`, that will now accept `Mat` instead of `Mat3b`.

Full code for reference:

```
void flip_lr(const Mat3b& src, Mat3b& dst)
{
    Mat3b _dst(src.rows, src.cols);
    for (int r = 0; r < _dst.rows; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < _dst.cols; ++c) {
            _dst(r, c) = src(r, src.cols - 1 - c);
        }
    }
    dst = _dst;
}

void custom_flip(const Mat3b& src, Mat3b& dst, int code)
{
    if (code > 0)
    {   // Flip x axis
        flip_lr(src, dst);
    }
    else if (code == 0)
    {
        // Flip y axis
        dst = src.t();
        flip_lr(dst, dst);
        dst = dst.t();
    }
    else // code < 0
    {
        // Flip x and y axis
        flip_lr(src, dst);
        dst = dst.t();
        flip_lr(dst, dst);
        dst = dst.t();
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat3b flipped;
    flip(img, flipped, -1);

    Mat3b custom;
    custom_flip(img, custom, -1);

    imshow("OpenCV flip", flipped);
    imshow("Custom flip", custom);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Your answer helped me lot. :)

Comment: @sturkmen at a first glance I agree with the answer there. Also cache plays an important role in your test, which may bias the results. Try with times = 10 for example. Try also switching the order of the tests and you'll get different results. Also, the first time you're calling `flip` you're creating the DstImg. Create it at the beginning.

Comment: @Miki thanks for your comment. i switched the order but the results are same.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV's flip function uses internal [flipHoriz or flipVert](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/copy.cpp#L561-L642) functions.

```
static void
flipHoriz( const uchar* src, size_t sstep, uchar* dst, size_t dstep, Size size, size_t esz )
{
    int i, j, limit = (int)(((size.width + 1)/2)*esz);
    AutoBuffer<int> _tab(size.width*esz);
    int* tab = _tab;

    for( i = 0; i < size.width; i++ )
        for( size_t k = 0; k < esz; k++ )
            tab[i*esz + k] = (int)((size.width - i - 1)*esz + k);

    for( ; size.height--; src += sstep, dst += dstep )
    {
        for( i = 0; i < limit; i++ )
        {
            j = tab[i];
            uchar t0 = src[i], t1 = src[j];
            dst[i] = t1; dst[j] = t0;
        }
    }
}

static void
flipVert( const uchar* src0, size_t sstep, uchar* dst0, size_t dstep, Size size, size_t esz )
{
    const uchar* src1 = src0 + (size.height - 1)*sstep;
    uchar* dst1 = dst0 + (size.height - 1)*dstep;
    size.width *= (int)esz;

    for( int y = 0; y < (size.height + 1)/2; y++, src0 += sstep, src1 -= sstep,
                                                  dst0 += dstep, dst1 -= dstep )
    {
        int i = 0;
        if( ((size_t)src0|(size_t)dst0|(size_t)src1|(size_t)dst1) % sizeof(int) == 0 )
        {
            for( ; i <= size.width - 16; i += 16 )
            {
                int t0 = ((int*)(src0 + i))[0];
                int t1 = ((int*)(src1 + i))[0];

                ((int*)(dst0 + i))[0] = t1;
                ((int*)(dst1 + i))[0] = t0;

                t0 = ((int*)(src0 + i))[1];
                t1 = ((int*)(src1 + i))[1];

                ((int*)(dst0 + i))[1] = t1;
                ((int*)(dst1 + i))[1] = t0;

                t0 = ((int*)(src0 + i))[2];
                t1 = ((int*)(src1 + i))[2];

                ((int*)(dst0 + i))[2] = t1;
                ((int*)(dst1 + i))[2] = t0;

                t0 = ((int*)(src0 + i))[3];
                t1 = ((int*)(src1 + i))[3];

                ((int*)(dst0 + i))[3] = t1;
                ((int*)(dst1 + i))[3] = t0;
            }

            for( ; i <= size.width - 4; i += 4 )
            {
                int t0 = ((int*)(src0 + i))[0];
                int t1 = ((int*)(src1 + i))[0];

                ((int*)(dst0 + i))[0] = t1;
                ((int*)(dst1 + i))[0] = t0;
            }
        }

        for( ; i < size.width; i++ )
        {
            uchar t0 = src0[i];
            uchar t1 = src1[i];

            dst0[i] = t1;
            dst1[i] = t0;
        }
    }
}
```

// you can use it with a small modification as below

```
void myflip( InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, int flip_mode )
{
CV_Assert( _src.dims() <= 2 );
Size size = _src.size();

if (flip_mode < 0)
{
    if (size.width == 1)
        flip_mode = 0;
    if (size.height == 1)
        flip_mode = 1;
}

if ((size.width == 1 && flip_mode > 0) ||
    (size.height == 1 && flip_mode == 0) ||
    (size.height == 1 && size.width == 1 && flip_mode < 0))
{
    return _src.copyTo(_dst);
}

Mat src = _src.getMat();
int type = src.type();
_dst.create( size, type );
Mat dst = _dst.getMat();

size_t esz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(type);

if( flip_mode <= 0 )
    flipVert( src.ptr(), src.step, dst.ptr(), dst.step, src.size(), esz );
else
    flipHoriz( src.ptr(), src.step, dst.ptr(), dst.step, src.size(), esz );

if( flip_mode < 0 )
    flipHoriz( dst.ptr(), dst.step, dst.ptr(), dst.step, dst.size(), esz );
}
```