# How to relate an image with another image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, reflection

I'm doing this project in OpenCV C++ where i make the reflection of a given image, just like the flip function but with the coordinates of each pixel. the problem is that the image output that i get is all blue with a line horizontally, i believe that my code is only affecting the first channel.

I tried to do `imageReflectionFinal.at<Vec3b>(r,c) = image.at<Vec3b>(r,c);` in order to solve it, but nothing changed. I'll leave the code below, thanks in advance.

```
    Mat image = imread("image_dir/image.jpg");
    Mat imageReflectionFinal = Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type());
    for(unsigned int r=0; r<image.rows; r++) {
        for(unsigned int c=0; c<image.cols; c++) {
                imageReflectionFinal.at<Vec3b>(r,c) = image.at<Vec3b>(r,c);
                Vec3b sourcePixel = image.at<Vec3b>(r,c);
                imageReflectionFinal.at<Vec3b>(r, c) = (uchar)(c, -r + (220)/2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `(uchar)(c, -r + (220)/2)` -- that comma is a comma operator, therefore this is the same as `static_cast<uchar>(110 - r)`. Setting the blue channel of each pixel to this value doesn't make any sense, hence the result. | There's also overflow involved and an off-by one error in the same statement.

Comment: Ow dang! Computers are so resilient nowadays. Back in the day, mainframes would have caught fire with so many programming errors.

Comment: What is the reason of not using *flip* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use [flip](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20flip(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20flipCode)) function, you can change the *x-coordinates(cols)* of each *rows* mirrorly. Here is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main() {

    //You can change as "Mat3b" for the 3-channel images
    Mat1b image = imread("/ur/image/directory/image.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat1b imageReflectionFinal = Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type());
    for(unsigned int r=0; r<image.rows; r++) {
        for(unsigned int c=0; c<image.cols; c++) {

            imageReflectionFinal(r, c) = image(r, image.cols - 1 - c);
            //y-axis(r) doesnt change only x-axis(cols) mirroring 
        }
    }

    imshow("Result",imageReflectionFinal);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[This answer is also my reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055410/how-to-do-flipping-without-using-the-inbuilt-function-flip-in-opencv)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, i did it successfully, now i'm trying to apply a x and y axis mirroring, i saw the link you left but couldn't fully understand it. So now i created another blank image, to make image > x axis mirroring to imageReflection > y axis mirroring to imageReflectionFinal, and end up with this: `                    imageReflection(r, c) = image(r, image.cols - 1 - c);
                    imageReflectionFinal(r, c) = imageReflection(imageReflection.rows - 1 - imageReflection.cols, c);`

I'm still playing with it but the image seems to always go off bounds.